# MySQL - Total count & rate of change in a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to extract the total number of website hits plus the rate of change(rate of increase/decrease) per client per city per day as a percentage in a single SQL query but not able to get it right.

I've created an example at

> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd279/8

Could I please request assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get percentage based increase/decrease

```
select 
  t1.HitDate,
  t1.City,
  t1.Client,
    SUM(t1.NumVisits),
  IFNULL(((SUM(t1.NumVisits)  -   IFNULL((SELECT SUM(t2.NumVisits) FROM PAGE_HITS t2 WHERE t2.HitDate = t1.HitDate-1 AND t2.City = t1.City AND t2.Client = t1.Client), 0)) * 100) / IFNULL((SELECT SUM(t2.NumVisits) FROM PAGE_HITS t2 WHERE t2.HitDate = t1.HitDate-1 AND t2.City = t1.City AND t2.Client = t1.Client), 0),0)  as rate_of_change
from
  PAGE_HITS t1
WHERE
t1.Client='C'
 group by
   HitDate,
   City
   ORDER BY HitDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding inner join, it has wrong condition anyway (`t1.hitDate = t2.hitDate and t1.hitDate-1 = t2.hitDate` which can't be satisfied):

```
select 
  t1.HitDate,
  t1.City,
  t1.Client,
  SUM(t1.NumVisits)  -   IFNULL((SELECT SUM(t2.NumVisits) FROM PAGE_HITS t2 WHERE t2.HitDate = t1.HitDate-1 AND t2.City = t1.City AND t2.Client = t1.Client), 0)  as rate_of_change
from
  PAGE_HITS t1
WHERE
t1.Client='C'
 group by
   HitDate,
   City
   ORDER BY HitDate;
```

Comment: Hello Zbynek - Thank you very much. I've updated the fiddle to include more values to test. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29c94c/1 - Looks like it's displaying just the raw data value rather than the rate of change. Also, I'd like the rate of change to be displayed as a percentage please.

Comment: That makes sense as for each row there is no row for previous date. Insert some data to get the difference. Regarding percentage - change `-` to `/`.

Comment: Thank you Zbynek. Highly appreciate your help. I've posted my answer below this just for complete reference of getting a percentage based calculation.

Answer (score 0):

first make a unique number like rownum 
and make the same query
and join the rownum columns
then you can see former month as new column and calculate the changing rate.

```
SELECT  A.HitDate, A.City, A.sumThis, B.sumFormer, (A.sumThis / B.sumFormer - 1) * 100 as 'ChangingRate'
From    (
        select @rownum1:=@rownum1 + 1 as 'rownum1', HitDate, City, sum(NumVisits) as 'sumThis'
        from page_hits, (Select @rownum1:=0) R
        Where client = 'C'
        Group by HitDate, City
        ) A
Left Join (
        select @rownum2:=@rownum2 + 1 as 'rownum2', HitDate, City, sum(NumVisits) as 'sumFormer'
        from page_hits, (Select @rownum2:=0) R
        Where client = 'C'
        Group by HitDate, City
        ) B On A.rownum1 - 1 = B.rownum2
```